# Using Arrays in Singleton Class in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

PetInfo.class

```
class PetInfo {

    static let shared: PetInfo = PetInfo()

    lazy var petArray: [PetInfo] = []
    var PetID:Int
    var PetName:String
    ...

    init(){ .. }
}
```

ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var PetArray = PetInfo.shared.petArray

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let pet = PetInfo() 
        pet.PetName = "Jack"
        PetArray.append(pet).        **Create Object and gave a name**


        print(PetArray[0].PetName) //works!

    }
}
```

secondViewController.swift

```
class secondViewController: UIViewController {

    var PetArray = PetInfo.shared.petArray

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let label: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        ...
        label.text = PetArray[0].PetName    **tried to print**
        return label
    }()
    
    view.addSubview(label)
    
    }
}
```

I want to share PetArray array in all of the view controllers.(It's more than two.)
It put data in the first VC, but doesn't work in the Second VC.
How can I share this array using a Singleton pattern?
Except for the array, It works perfect.(like String.. PetID, PetName.. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array in swift is implemented as Struct, which means Array is a value type and not a reference type. Value types in Swift uses **copy on write (COW)** mechanism to handle the changes to their values.

So in your `ViewController` when you assigned

```
var PetArray = PetInfo.shared.petArray
```

your `PetArray` was still pointing to the same array in your `PetInfo.shared` instance (I mean same copy of array in memory) . But as soon as you modified the value of `PetArray` by using

```
PetArray.append(pet)
```

COW kicks in and it creates a new copy of `petArray` in memory and now your `PetArray` variable in your ViewController and `PetInfo.shared.petArray` are no longer pointing to same instances instead they are pointing to two different copies of array in memory.

So all the changes you did by using `PetArray.append(pet)` is obviously not reflected when you access `PetInfo.shared.petArray` in `secondViewController`

**What can I do?**

remove `PetArray.append(pet)` and instead use `PetInfo.shared.petArray.append(pet)`

**What are the other issues in my code?**

**Issue 1:**

Never use **Pascal casing** for variable name `var PetArray = PetInfo.shared.petArray` instead use **camel casing** `var petArray = PetInfo.shared.petArray`

**Issue 2:**

```
class PetInfo {

    static let shared: PetInfo = PetInfo()

    lazy var petArray: [PetInfo] = []
    var PetID:Int
    var PetName:String
    ...

    init(){ .. }
}
```

This implementation will not ensure that there exists only one instance of `PetInfo` exists in memory (I mean it cant ensure pure singleton pattern), though you provide access to instance of `PetInfo` using a static variable named `shared` there is nothing which stops user from creating multiple instances of `PetInfo` simply by calling `PetInfo()` as you did in `let pet = PetInfo()`

rather use `private init(){ .. }` to prevent others from further creating instances of `PetInfo`

**Issue 3:**

You are holding an array of `PetInfo` inside an instance of `PetInfo` which is kind of messed up pattern, am not really sure as to what are you trying to accomplish here, if this is really what you wanna do, then probably you can ignore point two (creating private init) for now :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution to use Combine and Resolver frameworks. Works perfectly in my case with shared arrays.

In your case it could be

```
import Combine
import Resolver // need to add pod 'Resolver' to Podfile and install it first 


// Data Model
struct PetInfo: Codable {
    var PetID:Int
    var PetName:String
    ...
} 

// Repository to read manage data (read/write/search)

class PetRepository: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var petArray = Array<PetInfo>()
 
    override init() {
        super.init()
        load()
    }
    
    private func load() {
       // load pets info from server 
    }
}
```

Need to add AppDelegate+Injection.swift that will contain repository registration:

```
import Foundation
import Resolver

extension Resolver: ResolverRegistering {
  public static func registerAllServices() {
    // Services
    register { PetRepository() }.scope(application)
    
  }
}
```

Then use it in any controllers

```
import UIKit
import Combine
import Resolver

class ViewController: UIViewController { 
     @LazyInjected var petRepository: PetRepository

     private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        petRepository.$petArray
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .debounce(for: 0.8, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
        .sink { [weak self] petInfos in
            
            // set UI here 
            
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)

        
     }

      

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `PetInfo` to be a singleton, make its initializer `private`:

```
class PetInfo {

    static let shared: PetInfo = PetInfo()

    lazy var petArray: [PetInfo] = []
    var PetID:Int
    var PetName:String
    ...

    private init(){ .. } // !!
}
```

This way, any attempt to create new instances (like you do in your first ViewController) will fail, and will remind you to always use `PetInfo.shared` to access the singleton.